# ACRA like crash reporting library for C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling

For Android there exists an open source library called [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) which allows you to automatically report application crashs and (optionally logs) to a [Google Document Spreadsheet](http://docs.google.com) or [custom submit service URL](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#Reports_destination).

Is there any similar library for C# .NET ? An open source is preferred.

Comment: There are plenty of suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c-sharp) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361918/best-crash-reporting-framework-for-net-desktop-applications)

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c-sharp/1210737#1210737

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does [NBug](http://nbug.codeplex.com/) meet your needs? According to the site, crash reports can be submitted to anywhere you can POST, as well as a variety of other endpoints.